# SVG progress bar to move anti clockwise using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, progress-bar

I want a progress bar that moves anti-clockwise from 9 o'clock but in my code it is running from 3 o'clock clockwise also i want it to have a gradient finish which is blended smoothly. I tries the scaleX but its also not working

```
<pre><code>
<html>
  <head>
 <style>
    circle{
 fill: none;
 stroke: url(#GradientColor);
 stroke-width:20px;
 stroke-dasharray:435;
 stroke-dashoffset:435;
 animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
 }
 @keyframes anim {
 100%{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="progress">
    <div class="outter_circle">
        <div class="inner_circle">
            <div>HTML</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200px" height="200px">
    <defs>
       <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
          <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#6528F7" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#A076F9" />
       </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" stroke-linecap="round" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code is working fine for clock wise

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative value for `stroke-dashoffset`

```css
circle {
 fill: none;
 stroke: url(#GradientColor);
 stroke-width: 20px;
 stroke-dasharray: 435;
 stroke-dashoffset: -435;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 animation: anim 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <div class="outter_circle">
        <div class="inner_circle">
            <div>HTML</div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200px" height="200px">
    <defs>
       <linearGradient id="GradientColor">
          <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#6528F7" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#A076F9" />
       </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="70" />
</svg>
```